# Web Application em ASP.NET MVC CRUD com MS access

Tags: asp.net, mvc, microsoft-access, crud

Estou fazendo um trabalho, e preciso fazer uma aplicação web para acompanhamento de tarefas.
As exigências são essas do tópico. É um web application feito em ASP.NET MVC e banco de dados access criando um CRUD.
Estou com dificuldade de passar da parte de conectar o banco de dados.
Até o momento eu já criei o banco de dados, criei a conexão pelo server solution. Após isso criei o Web app MVC 5 no visual studio.
Neste momento começam minhas duvidas.
Encontrei na internet que é necessário (caso não tenha aparecido no Web.config ) adicionar o seguinte código :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConexaoMSAccess"connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|Cadastro.mdb" 
 providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Ok eu adiciono esse código, depois disso eu preciso adicionar um arquivo na pasta App_data, no caso o BD. Quando faço isso
aparece outra conexão no server solution, com o mesmo nome da que eu já havia feito.
Minha segunda duvida já seguindo um pouco a diante, neste momento eu devo criar uma class nova na pasta model. Esta class terá
os métodos de get e set de todas as colunas da minha tabela. Isso esta correto? 
Depois disso qual é o próximo passo para o CRUD?

Comment: Você poderia ver algum tutorial no youtue e seguir passo-a-passo e conseguiria fazer um crud em asp.net e mvc.